# Different number of "strings" (for loops"

Tags: bash, shell-script

Let say user choose 5 (antall).
I want then to print 5+6+7+8+4 (for instans).
In my script i get this print:

```
5+6+7+8+4**+**
```

How to get rid of the last +??
(I have tried echo "+" in a for loop, but havent manage to get i right)

My script:

```
plusse () {

while true; do
random=0
summit=0
read -p "Hvor mange tall vil du plusse>> " antall
echo "Hva er?  "


for (( i=1; i<=$antall; i++ )); do
random=$(( RANDOM % 10 ))
summit=$(( summit + $random ))

echo -n "$random "
    echo -n "+"
done
echo
read -p "Svaret mitt er>> " svarr
echo "$summit"
    if [[ $svarr == $summit ]]; then
        echo "Gratulerer! $svarr er riktig svar! "
        read -p "Vil du fortsette?>> " fortsette
            case $fortsette in
                ja|j|JA|Ja|y|Yes)   continue 
                                    ;;
                nei|n|Nei|n|N)      break 1
                                    ;;
                *)                  exit 1
                                    ;;
            esac
    else
        echo "Beklager, $svarr er feil. Riktig svar er $summit"
        read -p "Vil du fortsette?>> " fortsette
            case $fortsette in
                ja|j|JA|Ja|y|Yes)   continue
                                    ;;
                nei|n|Nei|n|N)      break 1
                                    ;;
                *)                  exit 1
                                    ;;
            esac

    fi
done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
for (( i=1; i<=$antall; i++ )); do
random=$(( RANDOM % 10 ))
summit=$(( summit + $random ))

echo -n "$random "
    echo -n "+"
done
```

will *always* append a `+` after the chosen digit.  You might want instead to do something like:

```
prefix=""
for (( i=1; i<=$antall; i++ )); do
    random=$(( RANDOM % 10 ))
    summit=$(( summit + $random ))
    echo -n "${prefix}${random}"
    prefix="+"
done
```